# How to start activity in adapter

Tags: android, firebase, android-intent, android-activity, adapter

What I am trying to do is start an activity in my adapter but it seems that I'm getting an error on my other adapter.

`java.lang.ClassCastException: com.lim.fiture.fiture.models.ProgramTracker cannot be cast to com.lim.fiture.fiture.models.ProgramExercise`

the error points on my `DayExerciseAdapter` which it only contains two things; exerciseName and exerciseReps.

**This is my DayExerciseAdapter** *this is where the error is*

```
public class DayExerciseAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DayExerciseAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private Context context;
private ArrayList<ProgramExercise> programExercises;

public DayExerciseAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ProgramExercise> programExercises) {
    this.context = context;
    this.programExercises = programExercises;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.day_exercise_layout_item, parent, false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.exerciseName.setText(programExercises.get(position).getExerciseName().toUpperCase());
    holder.exerciseReps.setText(String.valueOf(programExercises.get(position).getReps()));


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return programExercises.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView exerciseName, exerciseReps, doneTxt;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        exerciseName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.exerciseName);
        exerciseReps = itemView.findViewById(R.id.exerciseReps);
        doneTxt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.doneTxt);


    }
}
}
```

**This is where I am starting my activity intent**

```
public class UserProgramWeekAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UserProgramWeekAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private Context context;
private ArrayList<ProgramTrackerWrapper> programTrackers;


public UserProgramWeekAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ProgramTrackerWrapper> programTrackers) {
    this.context = context;
    this.programTrackers = programTrackers;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_user_program_week_adapter, parent, false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
    return viewHolder;

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(UserProgramWeekAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Log.d("UserProgramWeekAdapter", "Day: " + programTrackers.get(position).getDay());
    Log.d("UserProgramWeekAdapter", "Size: " + programTrackers.get(position).getProgramTrackers().size());
    holder.dayTxt.setText(programTrackers.get(position).getDay());

    holder.numberofExercises.setText(programTrackers.get(position).getProgramTrackers().size() + " exercise/s");
    boolean isFinished = false;
    final int sublistSize = programTrackers.get(position).getProgramTrackers().size();
    for (int i = 0; i < sublistSize; i++) {
        if (programTrackers.get(position).getProgramTrackers().get(i).isProgramExerciseFinished()) {
            isFinished = true;

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return programTrackers.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView dayTxt, exerciseCompleted, numberofExercises;
    CardView dayCard;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {

        super(itemView);

        dayTxt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.dayTxt);
        exerciseCompleted = itemView.findViewById(R.id.exerciseCompleted);
        numberofExercises = itemView.findViewById(R.id.numberofExercises);
        dayCard = itemView.findViewById(R.id.dayCard);
        dayCard.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ((StartProgramActivity) context).setWeekExercisesData(getAdapterPosition());
                ArrayList<ProgramTracker> programTrackerWrappers = ((StartProgramActivity) context).getDayOfWeekExercises();
                if (programTrackerWrappers.size() > 0) {
                    context.startActivity(new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), DayExerciseActivity.class).putExtra("programExercises", programTrackerWrappers));

                }else {
                    CustomToast customToast = new CustomToast(context);
                    customToast.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                    customToast.setBackground(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.color_2));

                    customToast.showErrorToast("No exercises for this day.");
                }


            }
        });
    }


}
```

**What I am getting: //error//**
[image]

Comment: on which line do you get this error?

Comment: hi sir! i added a photo of where i am getting my error. kindly check

Comment: Not related to error, but dont use `context.getApplicationContext()` in `Intent` from UI. Use simple `Context`

Comment: Your error resides somewhere between `ProgramExercise` and `ProgramTracker`. Check the casting how it is made, is `ProgramTracker` parent class or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Error in DayExerciseActivity"

Firstly you should use context instead of context.getApplicationContext and now talk about the problem 
you are passing Arrylist of **programTracker** in putExtra 
 **context.startActivity(new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), DayExerciseActivity.class).putExtra("programExercises", programTrackerWrappers));**

And I am sure that you are in DayExerciseActivity parsing it by ArrayList of **programExercise** that's why you are getting this casting error.because programTracker can not cast in to programExersce